How to change Icon color and lable color different in SlidableAction?
I am currently facing an issue with the SlidableAction in Flutter. When I set the foreground color, it changes the color of both the icon and the text simultaneously. My goal is to customize the appearance by allowing the icon and the label to have different colors. This differentiation is crucial for my design, as it enhances the visual hierarchy and overall user experience.
I would like to know if there is a way to achieve this. Specifically, I am looking for a method to set the icon color and label color independently within the same SlidableAction. For instance, I want to set the icon to one color, say red, while the label could be a contrasting color, such as blue.
Is there a way to accomplish this without affecting the entire foreground color of the SlidableAction? If anyone has experience with this or can provide guidance on how to implement this feature in Flutter, I would greatly appreciate your insights. Any code examples or suggestions on how to customize the colors effectively would be extremely helpful

Flutter's SlidableAction doesn't directly allow you to style the icon and label separately, but you can work around this by creating a custom widget inside SlidableAction.
Instead of using the default SlidableAction, use a Slidable with a CustomSlidableAction, and then customize the child widget to display both the icon and text with different styles.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_slidable/flutter_slidable.dart';

class CustomSlidableExample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Custom Slidable Action')),
      body: Slidable(
        key: const ValueKey(0),
        endActionPane: ActionPane(
          motion: const ScrollMotion(),
          children: [
            CustomSlidableAction(
              onPressed: (context) {
                // Action for the first button
              },
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.archive, color: Colors.white), // Icon color
                  SizedBox(height: 4), // Spacing between icon and text
                  Text(
                    'Archive',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow), // Text color
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            CustomSlidableAction(
              onPressed: (context) {
                // Action for the second button
              },
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.white), // Icon color
                  SizedBox(height: 4), // Spacing between icon and text
                  Text(
                    'Delete',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black), // Text color
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text('Swipe me for actions!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: CustomSlidableExample()));
}

